# Trying to print out a object with a toString method I made, getting what I believe to be is hashCode? How do I output a String?

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, system.out

So I currently trying to get my objects (in this case Person, Student, Employee, or hourlyEmployee) to print from an object array that stores all of their data. The array itself is working correctly, however when I try to print out a Person object, say for example in this case a student named billy, which then consists of a String name, int Social Security Number, int age, String gender, String address, int telephone, double GPA, String Major, and int yearOfGraduation in that order, it does print out the information correctly. Here is how I create the objects:

```
private Person billy = new Student("Billy", 111111111, 19, "Male", "404 Test Ave S", 1111111111, 4.0, "Business and Economics", 2018);
```

Here is the toString method I made in the Student class that descends from the parent class Person:

```
public String toString(String name, int ssn, int age, String gender, String address, int telephone, double GPA, String major, int grad){
    String superResult = super.toString(name, ssn, age, gender, address, telephone);
    String result = "\nGPA: " + GPA + "\nMajor: " + major + "\nGraduation Year: " + grad;
    return superResult + result;
}
```

and finally here is how I am trying to output it with the array:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < user.getPeople().length; i++){
            String string = user.getPeople()[i].toString();
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

in this case it is supposed to go through the array, and print out all of the values that it has in it. I do not think it is something with the for-loop itself, but something with the way I am converting the values of the objects into a string format.

Is there a way to convert from hashCode into the intended String, or a way so it would print out as a normal String in the first place?

Comment: The below answers look correct. I just have side note: If you are using an IDE (such as Eclipse), then you can use IDE's utility to generate the "toString" method. For example in Eclipse:  Open the Java file. And then go to Eclipse's Menu Bar and select "Source", and then click on "generate toString()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The toString override method from the Object class takes no parameters but yours does:

```
public String toString(String name, int ssn, int age, String gender, String 
    address, int telephone, double GPA, String major, int grad) {
   //....
}
```

The correct signature is:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   // your code here
}
```

When overriding methods don't forget the `@Override` annotation as this will let the compiler tell you when you are in error (like you are above).

Comment: Wow that was way more simple that I thought. It makes sense now, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You created a different `toString` method, with many arguments, than the one you called, with no arguments, that `Person` inherited from `Object`.  The `Object` version is responsible for the output you're seeing.

Remove all those parameters from your `toString` method, and construct the string you're returning with the instance variables of your `Person` class.  Also, use the `@Override` annotation on the method, to ensure that you're really overriding a method.

Comment: Is there any way I can call a specific one based off of what type of object the array is on? Say it was a Person it would call the toString() method I created in Person, but then when it is on a Student it uses that toString method I created in student.

Comment: You have to invoke the `toString()` as "method" of an "instance".  So  person1.toString()  will invoke the toString() method of the  person1 instance.

Comment: @FyreeW Override the `toString()` method in both `Student` and `Person`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I did not realize that I had to remove the parameters, and also override the toString method that was built in.

Answer (score 3):

You have done a method Overloading instead of a method overriding. You need to override the Object's method toString() to achieve this.

Comment: I got them confused for the same thing, which they are definitely not. Thank you for the assistance!